# How to get into image manipulation programming?

Tags: c++, image-processing, image-manipulation

How can I do simple thing like manipulate image programmatically ? ( with C++ I guess .. )
jpgs/png/gif .....

Comment: I would not call just reading .jpg images a "simple" thing, unless you're using a dedicated library to read those files.

The rest of the question depends on which type of manipulation you're looking for...

Comment: This question is neither specific nor useful.

Comment: I agree with the previous comments. You should really state in more detail what you want to do....are you looking for a library? Or do you want to dot it yourself? What image manipulations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

check out BOOST , it has a simple Image Processing Library called GIL. It also has extensions to import common formats.

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html

Answer (score 2):

Using .NET you have two options:

1. GDI+ from System.Drawing namespace (Bitmap class)
2. WPF engine wich can do a lot of things

If you want low level processing you can use unsafe code and pointers.

A Bitmap or Image is just a big array of bytes.
You need to learn:

- what is a stride (extra padding bytes after each row of pixels)
- how to compute the next row or a specific pixel location using width, height, stride
- the image formats RGB, ARGB, white&black
- basic image processing functions (luminosity, midtone, contrast, color detection, edge detection, matrix convulsion)
- 3D vectorial representation of a RGB color

Comment: With .Net have much more than two options......But the question is far too general to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how fancy you want to get, you may want to look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).  It's a computer vision library that has functions ranging from reading and writing images to image processing to advanced things like object detection.

Answer (score 2):

[Magick++](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/) is a C++ API for the excellent ImageMagick library.

An advantage of ImageMagick is that it can be used from the command-line and a [bunch](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php) of popular scripting and compiled languages too, and some of those might be more accessible to you than C++.